Ubuntu 22.04 LTS displays invert colors after the latest upgrade
The colors of icons, windows and images are inverted after the latest update. I tried to change the color profile in the settings to "Colorspace: sRGB" but it doesn't work either.
OS: Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS.
VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation CometLake-S GT2 [UHD Graphics 630] (rev 05)
Does anyone experience this issue? I appreciate very much if a solution is provided.


Add system information 2) What do you mean with "upgrade"? An upgrade is a move from one version to the next, e.g. from 22.04 to 24.04. Or do you mean an update, i.e. corrections to your current system? Use "Edit"  to adapt your question. Try making a new account and log in there: does the issue persist? Do you use the default graphics drivers?


I am facing the same issue after installing the latest updates. Apps like discord seems to be showing the correct color. I think apps downloaded using snaps are facing this issue.
Update:
I was able to fix this. I read that it is something to do with the oibaf PPA update. So first I deleted the repo using the following command:
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers -r

link for your reference: https://forum.linuxconfig.org/t/please-don-t-recommend-oibaf-ppa-for-ubuntu/6951
After doing this, I ran the following commands:
sudo dpkg -P --force-depends libdrm-amdgpu1 libdrm-common libdrm-intel1 libdrm-nouveau2 libdrm-radeon1 libdrm2 libegl-mesa0 libgbm1 libgl1-mesa-dri libglapi-mesa libglx-mesa0 libxatracker2 mesa-va-drivers mesa-vdpau-drivers mesa-vulkan-drivers


sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock


sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock


sudo apt --fix-broken install

Link for your reference: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=42&t=381601#google_vignette
then restart your computer and everything should be fixed :)
Credit to the folks that gave the solution in the other forums.
Apparently this has been a issue for many people as there was a oibaf PPA update in the last update.
Links to other similar issues:

https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=2486696#p2486696

https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=422997



Thanks a lot. It works!
